# How can I fill between two parabolas of this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill between two parabolas of this picture, but not correct. I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dashed}}
\newcommand{\RightAngle}[4][2.5pt]{%
        \draw ($#3!#1!#2$)
        --($ #3!2!($($#3!#1!#2$)!.5!($#3!#1!#4$)$) $)
        --($#3!#1!#4$) ;
        }
\begin{document}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\pgfmathsetmacro\AngleFuite{120}
\pgfmathsetmacro\coeffReduc{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro\clen{2}
\pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{\AngleFuite}
\begin{scope} [x = {(\coeffReduc*\cost,-\coeffReduc*\sint)},
y = {(1cm,0cm)},
z = {(0cm,1cm)}]
\path coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
coordinate (M) at (0,4,0)
coordinate (N) at (-3.46,2,0)
coordinate (P) at (-3.46,-2,0)
coordinate (Q) at (0,-4,0)
coordinate (R) at (3.46,-2,0)
coordinate (S) at (3.46,2,0)
coordinate (T) at (0,0,10)
coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
;
\draw[ dashed] (O)--(N) (O)--(M) (O)--(P) (O)--(Q) (O)--(R) (O)--(S) ;
\draw[dashed] (N)--(P) (P)--(Q) (O)--(T);
\draw[thick] (Q)--(R) (R)--(S) (S)--(M) (M)--(N) ;
\draw[thick,blue] (N)parabola(T) (Q)parabola(T) (R)parabola(T) (S)parabola(T) (M)parabola(T);
\draw[thick,dashed] (P)parabola(T) ;
\end{scope}
\foreach \v/\position in {N/right,M/right,P/right,O/below,Q/left,R/below,S/below,T/right} {
\draw[fill=black] (\v) circle (2pt) node [\position=5] {$\v$};
}
\draw [fill opacity=0.4,fill=orange!80!blue] (R) parabola (T) parabola (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I repair?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `[bend at end]` if you want to **flip** the parabola. That is, `(S) parabola (T)` is equivalent to `(T) parabola[bend at end] (S)`. See the manual page 155.

In your case, replace

> ```
> \draw [fill opacity=0.4,fill=orange!80!blue] (R) parabola (T) parabola (S);
> ```

by

```
\draw[fill opacity=0.4,fill=orange!80!blue](R)parabola(T)parabola[bend at end](S);
```

[image]

Comment: There is a small segment PQ out side
\draw[fill opacity=0.4,fill=cyan!80!blue](Q)parabola(T)parabola[bend at end](R);
How can I repair?

Comment: @toandhsp the Ti*k*Z library `intersection` will provide an answer.